# Custom Bootstrap theme causes drop downs to stop working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use a custom Bootstrap theme in my ASP web app but doing so causes drop downs to stop working.  Here's what I'm doing that reproduces the problem.

1) I create a new ASP.NET Web App and I check only MVC.

2) I edit Index.cshtml to include the following tab navigation code snippet from [Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/spacelab/).

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home">
    <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <p>Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown1">
    <p>Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown2">
    <p>Trust fund seitan letterpress, .</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Up until this point, everything works fine when I debug.

3) I right click the Content folder and add an existing item, bootstrap-spacelab.css, previously downloaded from [here](https://bootswatch.com/4/spacelab/bootstrap.css).

4) Then I change the following entry in BundleConfig.cs

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
```

to reference the new file

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap-spacelab.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

Now when I run the app, the look and feel of Spacelab is applied but the drop down no longer works.  Any guesses what I've done wrong?

Edit:

The bootstrap script reference is unchanged as

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap jQuery file included?

Comment: I edited the post to reflect that it was referenced by default and I didn't make any changes.

Comment: I think it's that you need a dropdown target. I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps you.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown_target" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_target">
......
```